# Sobolev Spaces: The difference between $W^{k,p}$ and $W^{k,p}_0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be an open set in $R^d$. I am confused about the differences between 
$$W^{k,p}(U):=\{u\in L^p(U): D^{\alpha}u\in L^p(U) \text{ for all } |\alpha|\le k\}$$ and $$W^{k,p}_0(U):=\overline{C_c^{\infty}(U)}$$
with the closure taken in the usual $W^{k,p}(U)$-norm.

$C_c^{\infty}(U)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(U)$ using the $L^p$-norm but it seems that it is not dense with the $W^{k,p}(U)$-norm.

My question is: What are the main differences between the two spaces and what functions are in   $W^{k,p}(U)$ that are not in $W^{k,p}_0(U)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [boundary traces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Traces).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this.

Comment: @Harald : What happens if $k\neq 1$?

Comment: Basically the same thing. The boundary trace is in $W^{k-1,p}$ on the boundary in that case. In any case, note that $W^{k,p}\subset W^{1,p}$ for $k=2,3,\ldots$.